# WAMP 2.5 : Opening projects from local host gives error "Web page is not available"?

Tags: php, wamp

I am using **WAMP 2.5**. I installed it properly.I placed my project inside **c://wamp/www** and now i'm accessing this project(i.e running the project) by using localhost. for that I use link 'Your projects' when this open up and after that when I click on my project it gives error '**This webpage is not available**'.
How can I access my project now ...

Comment: Please check whether you have started WAMP. If it is started, it shows green icon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server) This post should help explain why Virtual hosts are a good idea and also how to create Virtual Hosts on Apache/WAMPServer

Comment: No wamp is working well...

Comment: Their is no duplicate links also,

Comment: What happend when you use a url like this `localhost/projectfolder` or `localhost/projectfolder/filename.php`

Comment: It gives error 'This web page is not available'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey friends I got the answer and it solved my problem.
Open **index.php** located inside **www** folder and at **line number 30** change
**$suppress_localhost = true;** to **$suppress_localhost = false;** and refresh the page...